# File Not Found Error: Computer can't find an existing file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, filenotfounderror

I'm trying to read a file in the same folder as my main.py and am getting the following error.

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'central_park_census.csv'`

Here is my code:

```
import pandas
all_data = pandas.read_csv("central_park_census.csv")
print(type(all_data))
```

The issue is that the said file exists and is in the same folder as my main.py. I use the windows OS and this error has been prevalent with text files also. Please help if you can :))

Comment: Please share your code as well

Comment: How are you running this file?

Comment: code has been shared, sorry about that. I am running my code in my IDE.

Comment: Try using the full path; your IDE may use a different working directory.

Comment: Can be fixed by doing `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`

Comment: @Robert I just did, interestingly it worked when I used my relative path 'project\central_park_census.csv'.  How do I check my IDE's working directory?

Comment: current working directory: `os.getcwd()`

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by the **path**. Vscode identifies the path differently from other ides. Vscode retrieves files using the workspace as the current directory, not the currently opened folder. Therefore, please modify the path according to the workspace.